Average PowerBI
I want to calculate an average of a column after modifying it with a multiplication.
This means that I want to calculate the average of:
CA N with discount = [CA N]-[Discount 1]-[Discount 2]
For your information, here are the previous steps which:
Discount 1 = SUM(Account[CA])*0.35
Discount 2 = [Discount 1]*0.1
CA N with discount = [CA N]-[Discount 1]-[Discount 2]
Can you help me?
THANKS!
Gregory
I don't want to get the result:
Panier moyen = AVERAGE(Compte[CA])

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

Yes, I want to calculate the average of the "CA_N_avec_remise" column.
The "CA_N_avec_remise" column is equal to the "CA N" column - the "Remise 1" column - the "Remise 2" column.
enter image description here
